# Grav CMS on Windows

Tags: installation, content-management-system, grav

I installled grav from composer.
copied the [select2 doc](https://github.com/select2/select2) folder from git repository to users folder on my grav cms installation
When I open it on localhost it shows like the attached image.
What am I doing wrong
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a security measure, Grav 1.7 has enabled Twig function 'autoescape' by default. That means all output (stylesheets tags, scripts tags, content, etc.) are being escaped to prevent malicious code to run.

There are a few options to fix or workaround this:

- If you feel comfortable with code, you can go through all templates provided by the theme used and add filter `|raw` to output statements of which you are sure the data is safe. Eg. `{{ content | raw }}`, `{{ assets.css() | raw }}`, `{{ assets.js() | raw }}`, etc.
- Or you can add the following settings to `user/config/system.yaml` to disable auto-escaping:

  ```
  twig:
    autoescape: false
  strict_mode:
    twig_compat: true
  ```

Note:
As said, auto-escaping is a security measure, which makes option 2. only advisable as temporary solution until all templates have been fixed as mentioned in option 1.

Kind request:
If you post the same question on the repo mentioned above, it would be appreciated if you mention the cross-post.

Comment: thanks bro it got fixed. I am able to view the  contents

Comment: By the way, the owner of the plugin is not likely to fix the issue: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/6001